# How do I get the hidden badge on Steam for the SteamSale ARG?

Tags: steam

There seems to be a hidden badge on Steam which hints towards an ARG. How do I get this badge?

Comment: "Upcoming?" No, this is apparently the **end** of the ARG.  See Reddit's [/r/steamsaledetectives](https://www.reddit.com/r/steamsaledetectives) if you want to see how the various clues were discovered.

Comment: @Powerlord the activity on that subreddit seems to indicate that the hunt is ongoing. The comic with the clues is still ongoing, so I'd be surprised if the ARG is finished.

Comment: @murgatroid99 What they've discovered is that the stuff they missed is a [new wave file](https://t.co/Sc4rZZ7UPh) that has the text `LLLLHTBEEU` in its waveform.  This is an anagram of `BULLET HELL`, which was the clue to get they to Ikuraga that was found just by trying all non-translated tags for Undertale as passwords.

Answer (score 36):

1. Go to http://store.steampowered.com/app/253750 in your **normal browser** (you will need to log into Steam first if you are not already)
2. Wait until the site has been fully loaded
3. Type `search` on your Keyboard then press ENTER key
4. In the new popup window, enter the code `1v7531`

This is how it looks like:

[image: screenshot of popup]

---

Remark for 3: Don't click into the search field, just type it directly after the site has loaded without hovering or clicking anything.

After enterting this, you will be redirected to a page showing your new badge. The badge is also featureable on your profile. This does not work within the steam client.

Make sure you are logged into Steam while doing this, otherwise you will get an error. Thanks to [Gauzy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8827/gauzy) for the reminder.

[image: picture of the badge]

Comment: This worked for me, in Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Also works in edge, just tested it

Comment: Make sure you're logged in to your Steam account before doing this, otherwise you'll just get a null page.

Comment: The holiday sale is over now, and I can't seem to open the pop-up window. Am I too late?

Answer (score 10):

In case the other answer doesn't work, you can open the game [Ikaruga](http://store.steampowered.com/app/253750/)'s page through a browser, and run this code in the javascript console:

This will simulate the process of doing it:

```
$J.ajax({
    url: "http:\/\/store.steampowered.com\/actions\/clues",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: {key: "1v7531"}
}).done(function( result ) {
    if( result && result.url )
        window.location = result.url;
    else if( result.response )
        alert(result.response);
});
```

Source: [YanirX on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Afkk9GWg)

Comment: This helped a lot of users which asked for my help when I announced this over my group, hence I posted it here.

Comment: This method worked for me.